# How to show oroinc frontend datagrid conditionaly?

Tags: datagrid, yaml, orocrm, orocommerce

I have this grid in orocommerce: 

`logistics-agronomist-grid-frontend:
    extends: logistics-agronomist-grid-base
    acl_resource: kggroup_logistics_frontend_agronomist_view
    update: false
    delete: false
    source:
      type: orm
      query:
        where:
          and:
            - postCode.postCode  = :post_code
      bind_parameters:
        - post_code
    columns:
      agronomistPostCode:
        manageable: false
        renderable: false
    options:
      frontend: true`

I need somehow to make a condition if grid is empty render everything, so I need where if or something 
`query:
        where:
          and:
            - postCode.postCode  = :post_code`

At this place, i cannot figure out how to do it

I tried to look templates to make conditions, but grid renders somewhere in core, the place i cannot change, I tried to write CASE WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE '' END but i got errors, and IF statments doesn't exists in this query builder

Answer (score 1):

On the OroCommerce storefront, everything is rendered with layouts, including data grids. So you can use layouts to hide the grid. Take a look at [layout conditions](https://oroinc.com/b2b-ecommerce/doc/1.6/dev-guide/front-ui/layouts/layout-updates#conditions) or you can set a boolean value to the `visible` option of a block that renders the datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I used a controller to define frontend grid with if else

```
'agronomistTemplate' => $this->checkUserForPostCodeMatch() ?'logistics-agronomist-grid-frontend' : 'logistics-agronomist-full-grid-frontend'
```

And in grid layout:

```
- '@setOption':
      id: __datagrid
      optionName: grid_name
      optionValue: '=data["agronomistTemplate"]'
```